# Why does Laptop Firefox have Titlebar when Desktop Firefox does not?

Tags: gnome, firefox

Desktop:

[image]

Laptop:

[image]

Notice how the Desktop image has no titlebar above the tab and the Laptop image does have a titlebar above the tab? Why?

I confirmed both versions of Firefox are exactly the same and have the same theme and no extensions. Is this difference a result of some about:config setting or something? I would like for the Laptop version to NOT have a titlebar.

Comment: You can include images directly by clicking on the image icon above the posting area.

Comment: Click on `☰ > Customize` and uncheck "Title bar" in the lower left corner.

Comment: @DK Bose, I did click on the image icon when posting those images. I guess something got messed up with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Firefox's ☰ icon on Top-Right,
Then the **Customize...** option.

On Bottom-Left, **Uncheck** "Title Bar".
Done!

### Alternatively,

Click on **View** Menu Option,
Then Hover over **Toolbars** to show more items,
Click on **Customize...** option.

On Bottom-Left, **Uncheck** "Title Bar".
Done!

Comment: Method 1 and 2 appear to be very dependent on your desktop environment. Did you test in standard Ubuntu? If not, please remove these two methods, or at least indicate when these solutions apply.

Comment: Thanks @vanadium removing Them.